# Oracle SQL query to find if customers has orders

Tags: sql, oracle

For customers in Bergen, display customer number, order number, and order date if the customer has orders.

```
SELECT customernumber, ordernumber, orderdate

FROM customers

WHERE orders ???
```

I am stuck at the part where, how would I write this query to display if a customer has orders or not?.

Comment: can you at least put your data model ? how you relate customers and orders ? I guess the data is on different tables, doesn't it ?

Comment: `where exists (select 1 from orders...)` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of my crystal ball, my guess is that you need to join two tables (which will return rows only if that customer had some orders) and use a simple `WHERE` clause to filter people who live in Bergen:

```
select c.customernumber,
       o.ordernumber,
       o.orderdate
from customer c join orders o on o.customernumber = c.customernumber
where c.location = 'Bergen';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can the customers table contain people who do not have orders? Assuming yes since you're asking. How is the ordernumber field populated?

May just need to add this...

```
    where ordernumber is not null
```